# YouTube API Credentials - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API Browser key, I've got two keys here, one is mine that I created yesterday, the other one is from the sample project where I got the code from.
The problem is that if I use my own key, it won't work. It's only working the other key from a random user.

When I checked the console, I saw it is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

The temp key for testing the code is this:

```
AIzaSyDXpwzqSs41Kp9IZj49efV3CSrVxUDAwS0
```

You can create your own key at:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
```

My code is as follows:

Like this:

```
/*YouTube API V3*/

var youtube = 'CHANNEL_ID';

//YouTube API V3
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+youtube,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  data:{
    key:'KEY_GOES_HERE'
  },
  success: function(data) {   
    var subscribers = parseInt(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
    var k = kFormatter(subscribers);
    $('#posts .youtube .count').append(k); 
    getTotal(subscribers); 
  } 
});`
```

Comment: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` the error message is clear, you are trying to access element `0` from something that is undefined. Look at your code - find all the places you are accessing element `0`. It's a single place `data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount`. If that `[0]` is throwing the error, then whatever it's appended to is `undefined` - this happens to be `data.items`. So when you get `data` it doesn't have an `items` property. Therefore, check what response you are getting and modify your code to access it appropriately.

Comment: Just found the problem, it's related to how I configured the referrer in the API, but I configured as in the example: `*.example.com/*`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

All I had to do was using my domain name without any dots in the beginning and slashes in the end, inside the API CONSOLE, like this:

> Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional) Use
>   asterisks for wildcards. If you leave this blank, requests will be
>   accepted from any referrer. Be sure to add referrers before using this
>   key in production.
>        mysitename.com

It may take a few seconds, or minutes, to take effect after saving.
In any case, just keep that field empty if the error persists.
If it works one time and the other time it doesn't, like randomly working every time you refresh the page or browse to another page, just leave the field empty, it's not hosted in your own server anyway, blame google for being irresponsible with their API.